# Ошибка при подключении telegram widget

Tags: telegram-bot, typescript, vue3

Не могу подключить telegram widget
Создал телеграм бот через @botFather, выдал такой виджет:

```
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22" data-telegram-login="kyrgyztest" data-size="large" data-onauth="onTelegramAuth(user)" data-request-access="write"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onTelegramAuth(user) {
    alert('Logged in as ' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ' (' + user.id + (user.username ? ', @' + user.username : '') + ')');
  }
</script>
```

проект написан на vue3 composition API + Typescript.
выдает ошибку

> Username invalid

в файле views/auth/Login.vue

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const telegramWidget = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);


onMounted(() => {
  const widgetElement = telegramWidget.value;
  
  if (widgetElement) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22';
    script.setAttribute('data-telegram-login', 'kyrgyztest';
    script.setAttribute('data-size', 'large');
    script.setAttribute('data-radius', '20');
    // script.setAttribute('data-onauth', 'onTelegramAuth(user)');

    script.async = true;
    widgetElement.appendChild(script);
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="telegramWidget">Welcome</div>
</template>
```

в файле .env хранится

```
TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME="kyrgyztest"
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN="токен:токен-токен"
```

больше ничего не связывается.
Что я неправильно делаю, помогите, я новичок в этом.

Comment: я в этом не разбираюсь, но разве data-telegram-login не должнo, по правилам именования ботов, заканчиваться на "bot"?

Comment: Да, вы правы, но я и так пробовал, но тоже не получилось. Оказывается надо без вот этой штучки @ указать. И теперь другая проблема, так как мой проект запускается через http://localhost:8080 указать этот домен в @botFather через команду /setdomain не могу. Как я понял нужен реальный домен.
Или если вы знаете поделитесь опытом. 